# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core' in django

Tags: python, django

i installed latest version of django and created project and when i run server than this error occure
may be its latest verion of django problem but how to solve this i try to find solution but not able to solve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Comment: please add more context to your question.

Comment: Traceback or it didn't happen... ;-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.